# What are some ways to stream audio from a CDN so that it can't be downloaded?

Tags: audio, streaming, cdn

I'm looking for a way to stream audio from a CDN server so that the end-user can't download the audio without first signing up for a special account, but so that they can *preview* the (entire) audio prior to setting up an account.

What are the best technologies to do this with?

Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you that a savvy user will record the audio no matter what, due to the analog loophole... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole

Answer (score 0):

As @dykeag mentioned, what you are asking for is technically impossible to do completely, since one could always just record the audio output, either via an analog device or via a special audio driver.

However, there are various barriers in place to make this more difficult, though they all essentially rely on having a dedicated client program, encrypting the audio-stream that is being downloaded, and decrypting it in your client.